# Intellisense cannot find member functions of template class specialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, intellisense, template-specialization

I have this specialization:

```cpp
enum class Coordinate { CARTESIAN, POLAR };

template<arithmetic_char_const_excluded T>
    class Vector<T, 2, Coordinate::POLAR> {
```

And the class it specializes from, **after it**

```cpp
template<underlying_vector_type T, std::size_t Size, Coordinate type = Coordinate::CARTESIAN>
    class Vector {
```

Inside the second one, I have this constructor:

```cpp
// Conversion: polar --> cartesian form
template<arithmetic_char_const_excluded T2>
explicit Vector(const Vector<T2, 2, Coordinates::POLAR>& other) {
    _vector[0] = other.
}
```

And for reference, the concepts are:

```cpp
template<typename T> struct is_complex : std::false_type {};
template<typename T> struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
concept underlying_vector_type = 
    (is_complex<T>::value or std::is_arithmetic_v<T>) 
    and not std::is_same_v<T, char> 
    and not std::is_const_v<T>;

template<typename T>
concept arithmetic_char_const_excluded = 
    std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
    and not std::is_same_v<T, char>
    and not std::is_const_v<T>;
```

...Intellisense only shows the member functions of the main template when I type `other.` as shown in code snippet (3), instead of the member functions of the specialized class. Why is that?

Comment: Only a C++ compiler can fully understand C++ code, especially one that uses the latest and the most advanced parts of C++, like concepts. "Intellisense" is not a C++ compiler.

Comment: You can suggest a feature for Visual Studio [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion).